# Where can I find a manual for my old school bus?

Tags: truck, gmc, service-manual, motorhome

My father and I have a 1967 (we think--I have my suspicions that it's a 69-73, due to the fact that the 1967 model for GMC had a different hood) GMC 950 B-Series 12-window bus, long since converted into an RV by it's previous owners way back in the late 1970's. I am attempting to help him get it running, but we have a problem--I have no idea where to find proper torque specs, fluid recommendations, or other info.

This 1973 sales brochure shows what it looks like (bottom picture):
[image: GMC sales brochure, 1973]

As you might imagine, I'd rather have critical safety things torqued properly. So, are there any websites that might have the proper repair manual for the rolling chassis the bus body was put on?

Comment: Fluids are same as any other gm car or P/U of that era.

Answer (score 2):

Your library might have Chilton’s or Haye’s manuals for that era.  That’s what I used for all my vehicles back then.

Many have been digitized on [www.archive.org](http://www.archive.org).  when the copyrights expired but unlikely for this one.
However you   might find some restoration clubs.  https://archive.org/search.php?query=GMC%20B-Series&sin=TXT

I’ll let you do the searching.